# Maui App template - Windows - "The project doesn't know how to run the profile Windows Machine"

Tags: maui

**Raised this as [Issue #3725 at maui github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3725).

Repeating here for StackOverflow searches.**

#### Description

The message in the title pops up, whenever attempt to run a Maui App (unmodified) on Windows.

Works fine on Android.

I've run on Windows before, on earlier Previews.

#### Steps to Reproduce

In Visual Studio 2022 Preview (Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.1).

1. New Project - .NET MAUI App (Preview).
2. Select "Windows Machine" as target.
3. Run. (Green Arrow; Start Debugging)

Output from build indicates success:

> Build started...
> 1>------ Build started: Project: MauiApp3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
> 1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
> 1>MauiApp3 -> C:\Users\toolm\source\repos\MauiApp3\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041\win-x64\MauiApp3.dll
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Then the popup saying "The project doesn't know how to run the profile Windows Machine".

POSSIBLY RELATED: Sometimes when quit VS and load same project again, it hangs forever Preparing Solution. Only way out is to kill with Task Manager. Next time, it skips loading documents, and is able to proceed.

#### Version with bug

Preview 10 (current)

#### Last version that worked well

Unknown/Other (Had it running at one time; not sure which Preview.)

#### Affected platforms

Windows

#### Affected platform versions

"Framework (net6.0-windows 10.0.19041)"

#### Did you find any workaround?

No workaround. Rebooted. Deleted bin & obj. Ran maui-check (all green). Created a new project same steps. Tried running Android first. Tried not running Android first.

#### Relevant log output

none

Repo: https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/MauiApp3NoWindowsProfile